# How do I merge these UDP packets into an H264 NAL unit in Java?

Tags: android, udp, h.264

I have a TelloEDU drone which sends each NAL unit in 1-5 UDP packets (no its not an RTP stream, yes its super odd) I need to us Java, more specifically the Android SDK, to merge these packets into one NAL unit so that I may decode them.

My initial thought was to set the max size of the packets to around 2000bytes (larger than the largest packets) and then trim the trailing zeros and concantanate them together to form one NAL unit but I can't gurantee that the packet won't end in a necessary 0. Even if that wasn't a problem, something's wrong with my implementation and my decoder is throwing some weird green screen.

If you're curious here's how I concantanate the individual NAL unit frames. Each newFrame already has it's trailing zeros removed

```
public byte[] getNALUnit(){
            int i=0;
            byte[] NALUnit;
            NALUnit=Arrays.copyOf(initialFrame,initialFrame.length);

            while (i<10){
                byte[] newFrame = encodedVideo.getPacketData(true,true);
                byte[] compareHeader = Arrays.copyOfRange(newFrame,0,4);

                if (!Arrays.equals(compareHeader, H264Header)){ //Compares the current packets first 4 bytes with the H264 Header
                    NALUnit=concat(NALUnit,newFrame);
                    i++;
                }
                else{
                    initialFrame=newFrame;
                    return Arrays.copyOfRange(NALUnit,4,NALUnit.length); //return the NAL UNIT without the H264 Header
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you had told how your five packets looked like. And if you had told how the resulting byte array should look.. and if you had told what is is that you call a nal...

Comment: **(1)** Green screen is because no SPS or PPS or Keyframe... **(2)** In your received packet data, you need to scan the array for NALU start codes (is `00 00 00 01` for SPS/PPS/SEI data, and is usually `00 00 01` for I/P/B frames). **(3)** You keep data between beginning one start code until the beginning of next NALU. You scan with a **While** or **For** loop. Where you check if the Array's current position value matches the expected value, if yes then check if `Array[ i+1]` matches and repeat as needed.